# How to use COALESCE in updateOrCreate method in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql, coalesce

I need to update column if it is NULL. if column is not null just stay this value.

I have this query:

```
(new ApplicationReviewQuestion)->updateOrCreate(
    [
        'application_review_id' => $review->id,
        'number' => $question->number,
        'type' => $question->type,
        'application_grade_id' => $question->application_grade_id
    ], [
        'recommendation' => DB::raw("COALESCE(recommendation, '" . $question->recommendation ."')"),
        ...,
    ]
);
```

but goes on exception:

`Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "recommendation" does not exist LINE 1: ... values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, COALESCE(recommendat... ^ HINT: There is a column named "recommendation" in table "application_review_questions", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.`

any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the error says `column "recommendation" does not exist`: make sure the name of the column you want to update is correct, but this may depend on DB engine and framework versions.

Also using updateOrCreate, in case of *insert*, the column could be set to an unwanted value, as the record does not exist yet: the query executed would be something like (the numerical data here are invented):

```sql
insert into `application_review_questions` 
(`application_review_id`, `number`, `type`, `application_grade_id`, 
`recommendation`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values 
(123, COALESCE(recommendation, 'recommendation to insert'), 
456, 789, '2023-05-21 02:27:12', '2023-05-21 02:27:12')
```

try that in your SQL client and test the result: probably *recommendation* will be filled with empty string

Also in Laravel 10 *DB::raw* will no longer be directly usable and the example you provided should be revised completely

I advise you to do a search for the record first, if it exists you can perform an update, otherwise perform an insertion:

```
$applicationReviewQuestion = ApplicationReviewQuestion::where ('application_review_id', $review->id)
                                                      ->where('number', $question->number)  
                                                      ->where('type', $question->type)  
                                                      ->where('application_grade_id', $question->application_grade_id)
                                                      ->first();
                                                      
if ($applicationReviewQuestion instanceof ApplicationReviewQuestion) {
    
    if ($applicationReviewQuestion->recommendation === NULL) {
        
        $applicationReviewQuestion->recommendation = $question->recommendation;
        $applicationReviewQuestion->save();
    }
}
else {
    
    $applicationReviewQuestion = ApplicationReviewQuestion::create([
        'application_review_id' => $review->id,
        'number' => $question->number,
        'type' => $question->type,
        'application_grade_id' => $question->application_grade_id
        'recommendation' => $question->recommendation,
        //...,
    ]);
}
```